# Using filter to count array length with condition

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects called `places` where each object looks something like this:

```
{
  "name" : "London",
  "category" : "city"
}
```

I just use `<span>{{places.length}}</span>` for the total array length but now I would like to count the number of objects that have a category of `city` ideally using a filter directly within the view.

Something like:

```
{{places.length | filter: ...}}
```

but not sure how to write the filter?

Comment: Mind looking in angularjs documentation for filter?

Comment: The examples I've found are always part of `ng-repeat`

Comment: I agree with @tommyd456. This type of example was not easy to find on the internet. Thank you for asking this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
<span>{{ (places | filter : { category: 'city' } : true).length }}</span>
```

Comment: Cheers for this - really simple

Comment: Worked fine for me after I removed : true
i.e. <span>{{ (places | filter : { category: 'city' }).length }}</span>